# How to generate a 64 bit key in php

Tags: php, facebook, unique-key

I have been trying up with random number generators in php to generate keys for photos structure on the website I am building. I recently came to know that Facebook as well as Instagram fit there photo ids in 64 bit.

Facebook Engineering Note -: **http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919**
Instagram Engineering Note -: **http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram**

Just wanna know how these guys do it and fit various aspects like user id, timestamp in various bits to come up with 64 bits in total.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just generate an id and test, whether it exists, or not. Which problem do you have?

Comment: use IDs just like they do and then add padding , by the way facebook do padding in new user Ids you'll find new user ids like this : 

10001231231231 100023543455 .....etc

Comment: You interpreted it wrong. I need to know just this
"How do I fit a 60 character long random number in 41 bits".
Just answer this man!

Comment: @HaniffKumarMehta, demanding things from us will just get your question ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at this:

[64 bit key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7243552/1880925)

Now just replace random counter with current timestamp.