# Create unique numeric ID from multiple numeric IDs

Tags: java, algorithm

What is a good algorithm to generate a unique 64-bit ID starting from multiple numeric 64-bit IDs? Example:

> Input: [2, 9875, 0, 223568, ...] a list of random 64-bit IDs
>
> Output: a unique 64-bit numeric ID, that have to be the same for the given input

I'm looking a way to avoid ID collision.

---

My apologies for the unclear question.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to make your question clear

Comment: Some more constraints would be useful. For instance, if you know all IDs are at most 10 characters long, and you don't care how long the resulting ID is, you could just concatenate: 0000000002000000987500000000000000223568

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of the values of your multiple numeric 64-bit IDs?

Comment: @MrSmith42 No, in this context they are random, I'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If speed does not matter**, what about:

feeding all your ids in the md5-algorithm and than simply use

a) first 64 bits or
b) last 64 bits or
c) first 64 bits xor last 64 bits

---

**If speed matters**

What about:

**Step 1:** reorder the bytes of all 64 bit IDs (in a fixed but different order for each 64 bit ID of your Input.)(This might help a bit if the values are not really randomly distributed)

**Step 2:** xor all the rearranged 64 bit IDs to get the new 64 bit id.

---

If you have no extra information about the range of your 64 bit input IDs or the distribution of the values, there is no way to avoid collisions in a 'clever'/'best' way. Because whatever you come up with, you will always find a set of inputs which lead to collisions.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243552/how-to-generate-unique-64-bit-keys) old question will be useful for you if you want more information, but you can try this:

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID().hashCode()
```

If the previous solution didn't work in your case, try this:

```
private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()*100000);
```

Or [this](https://gist.github.com/tovbinm/7918175) algorithm (GitHub link).